# How to import a new Vertex Instruction (Line) in the Kivy Language?

Tags: python, kivy

I want that by default all my Line instances have a width of 2. Instead of adding `width: 2` each time I create a new instance, I am trying to create a new class (`MyLine`):

```
class MyLine (Line):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['width'] = kwargs.get('width') or 2.0
        Line.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

This actually works as soon as I call on it in Python:

```
 MyLine(points=[ix, iy, fx, fy])
```

However, I am unable to call on it from the Kivy Language. I tried to explicitly import the class:

```
#:import MyLine myfile.MyLine
```

I was wondering if this was possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try registering your instruction so kv knows about it.

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
Factory.register('Line', module='myfile')
```

you can look at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/factory_registers.py#L74 for the original register of Line.